# Unable to install PySimpleGUI on Windows "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySimpleGUI'"

Tags: python, installation, window, pysimplegui

So I'm trying to install PySimpleGUI and I'm not sure if it is installing correctly. This is what I get when I install it.

```
PS C:\Users\neisw> pip install --upgrade PySimpleGUI
Collecting PySimpleGUI
  Using cached PySimpleGUI-4.34.0-py3-none-any.whl (243 kB)
Installing collected packages: PySimpleGUI
Successfully installed PySimpleGUI-4.34.0
```

Then when I actually try and import it I get the error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SN_GUI.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PySimpleGUI
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySimpleGUI'
```

Comment: your directory or file name should not be `PySimpleGUI`

Comment: The file I called was "SN_GUI.py". I'm sorry, what are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm if PySimpleGUI under one of following paths before your import statement.

```py
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)
import PySimpleGUI
```

```
D:\Python\Project\OK
C:\Software\Python\python38.zip
C:\Software\Python\DLLs
C:\Software\Python\lib
C:\Software\Python
C:\Software\Python\lib\site-packages
C:\Software\Python\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Software\Python\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Software\Python\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
...
```

Above paths should be different as yours, most of time it will be like

```
lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI
```

IMO, installed environment is different as that when run your script.

Comment: Thank Jason! I just did that and it isn't in any of those folders so I'm guessing it means that it's not being installed correctly? Any idea how I can rectify that?

Comment: Need to check how to install library under your environment of executation.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem in Debian using venv. I removed the folders created by pip in

```
(venv)/lib/python3.11/site-packages
```

then downloaded `PySimpleGui.tgz` from Pypy and exctract it in the same folder above.
Finally I changed the name of the 2 folders to pysimplegui (lowercase).
  
When imported as `pysimplegui` it works.