# ImportError: No module named PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, installation, pysimplegui

I am attempting to use PySimpleGUI to create a very simple GUI, but when I run the command "python hello_world.py" I get the error:

```
File "hello_world.py", line 3, in <module>
    import PySimpleGUI as sg
ImportError: No module named PySimpleGUI
```

I've run the command "pip install PySimpleGUI" and it says "Successfully installed PySimpleGUI-4.55.1." I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Code snippet here:

```
# hello_world.py

import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.Window(title="Hello World", layout=[[]], margins=(100,50)).read()
```

Comment: try with: `python -m pip install PySimpleGUI` and then `python hello_world.py`

Comment: As per the documentation "pip3 install pysimplegui" try this

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those suggestions worked. It keeps telling me that PySimpleGUI is already installed, but won't run when I give the command "python hello_world.py".

Comment: check if this answer satisfies you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66425849/unable-to-install-pysimplegui-on-windows-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named/72589128#72589128

Comment: Check where the `python` by `where python` to make sure which python you run on your platform.

Answer (score 3):

check where python is installed

```
import os
import sys
print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))

>>C:\Program Files\Python310 #here 310 is python version your may be differrent
```

if this outputs inside **C:\Program Files\Python310**

check for `C:\Program Files\Python310\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI`

if its not there then Run CMD as admin and try `python -m pip install PySimpleGUI`

Answer (score 1):

Update pip to the current version via "python -m pip install --update pip".

It's strange, but my PySimpleGUI module became visible after I updated the pip from version 21.2.3 to version 22.0.4 via "python-m pip install --update pip".

Before the pip version update, the contents of my local environment looked like this:

```
(env) D:\work\PycharmProjects\demo>pip list  
Package     Version
----------- -------
flake8      4.0.1
mccabe      0.6.1
pip         21.2.3
pycodestyle 2.8.0
pyflakes    2.4.0
setuptools  57.4.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'D:\work\PycharmProjects\demo\env\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

After the update:

```
(env) D:\work\PycharmProjects\demo>pip list
Package     Version
----------- -------
flake8      4.0.1
mccabe      0.6.1
pip         22.0.4
pycodestyle 2.8.0
pyflakes    2.4.0
PySimpleGUI 4.57.0
setuptools  57.4.0
```

And the program hello_world.py it began to run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT Dec2021:

This seems to me like an bug with pip rather than PySimpleGUI. Try this https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/ reinstall pip in the python interpreter using this.

Original Answer:

You can check all the installed packages with

```
python3 -m pip list
```

And see if you find PySimpleGUI in it. If yes then python3 hello_world.py should work if not (i suspect latter) run

```
python3 -m pip install PySimpleGUI
```

Comment: So I ran python3 -m pip list and PySimpleGUI version 4.55.1 is there... Still doesn't work though.

Comment: are you able to access other packages like numpy?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, here's how I solved it.

First, run this code in whatever IDE you're using:

```
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)
```

This should give you a list of folders in your Python package. One of mine looked like this:

```
c:\Users\rohan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
```

Next, open up PowerShell and do `pip install PySimpleGUI` If PySimpleGUI is already installed, usually PS will provide you with the absolute path of PySimpleGUI. Once you find this, go there and select the one or two folders of PySimpleGUI. Finally, move those folders to the location that the list provided you with. Most of the time you will need to move it to (as shown above) AppData, then Local, then Programs, then Python, then whatever version of Python is in there, then Lib, then site-packages. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Had that problem. 
Copied my two missing packages to the project packages list, then erased the import and redid it (didn't work if I didn't erase the import before as it couldn't find the package). 
Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

For me Win 11, python 3.11 installation with pip. Pip freeze displays properly PySimplGUI (see image 1). I had to rename the package from PySimpleGUI to **pysimplegui** so that it works fine (see image 2).

[1 Pip Freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUDjb.png)

[my sites-package within my python 3.11 path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOddV.png)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe do this import:

```
import PySimpleGUI
```

and then the version of PySimpleGUI instead of:

```
import PySimpleGUI
```

Doing this:

```
C:/Users/Test> pip list
```

in the terminal, for me, it says there's PySimpleGUI installed.

Comment: Why would the package name include the version number?